# Массовая смена кодировка из ASCII в UTF-8

Tags: windows, кодировка

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: нужно массово сменить кодировки нескольких сотен скриптов из ASCII в UTF-8.

Погуглил, нашёл тулзу под названием UTFCast, но эта программа в итоге побила все кириллические символы (благо, на копии).

Проблема усложняется тем, что:

1. Машина на винде, возможности поднять линукс нет. Даже в виртуалке.
2. Скрипты раскиданы в различных каталогах.

Может быть, есть решение какое этой задачи под Windows?

Comment: А доступ к любому интерпретатору есть? Если есть php - можно использовать iconv и конвертнуть самому.

Comment: @KoVadim ну можно, в принципе, качнуть денвер. 
Сам чего т даже не подумал. 

Сейчас попробуем.

Comment: Можно взять версию iconv для Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681568/change-files-encoding-recursively-on-windows) рекомендуют воспользоваться Windows PowerShell и скриптом из 3 строчек:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
$content = $_ | Get-Content

Set-Content -PassThru $_.Fullname $content -Encoding UTF8 -Force}
```